# Sharing nice url on facebook - using copy and past on my wall

Tags: facebook, unicode, copy-paste, arabic, sharing

I have an nice URL includes Unicode Arabic text like the following:

http://www.ivotenow.org/ar/polls/view/1003/%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%AB%D8%B1%20%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%87%D9%88%20%D8%9F

When I copy and past it to my wall, I get the preview like following:

http://www.ivotenow.org/ar/polls/view/1003/أكثر%20أندية%20كرة%20القدم%20في%20السعودية%20جماهيرية%20هو%20؟

I used the Debug tool from Facebook and it shows the correct preview:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

And please note when I use shraethis.com widget it works fine.

Any Ideas please.

Regards,
Eco

Comment: Thanks lego for comment, same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811623/facebook-share-problem-for-non-english-urls

Comment: The problem you are linking to has already been solved. What is your specific problem? How does it differ from the one you are linking to?

Comment: I tried to use the same solution but it is not working for me, please try to copy and past the following URL, you will not get any preview image or description                  http://www.ivotenow.org/ar/polls/view/1022/%D9%87%D9%84%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%9F                                                                        Thank Leog :)

Answer (score 0):

I just testet the following url in the debug tool ([click here to see the result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.ivotenow.org/ar/polls/view/1022/%25D9%2587%25D9%2584%2520%25D8%25AF%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B3%25D8%25AA%2520%25D9%2581%25D9%258A%2520%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AC%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585%25D8%25B9%25D8%25A9%2520%25D8%25B9%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D8%259F)):

http://www.ivotenow.org/ar/polls/view/1022/%D9%87%D9%84%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%9F

Image and title are there but there are also still warnings you should fix:

> - The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> - og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
> - fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high
>     click-through rate.